# creating a debug window with delegate callback

Tags: c#, object, delegates, instance

I try to get working a debugger window which tell me what is going on in my code while running.
So I have one mainform which write in debug console when it runs. and a second form which write in my debug console too.

Now I found another way to do it but I'm wondering what it really do.
Source(my code but their Idea):: this site QA: Can I make a Form a singleton?

DebugConsole create a static Instance::

```
public partial class DEBUGConsole : Form
{
    public static DEBUGConsole Instance;

    public DEBUGConsole()
    {
        Instance = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    internal void SetValueFunction(string value)
    {  
        ListBoxDEBUG.Items.Add(value);
    }
}
```

Form1 create the Instance to share::

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public DEBUGConsole ConsoleDEB;
    internal SecondForm Formsnd2;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DEBUGConsole ConsoleDEB = new DEBUGConsole();
        ConsoleDEB.Show();
        DEBUGConsole.Instance.SetValueFunction("Hello 1");
        Formsnd2 = new SecondForm();            
        Formsnd2.Show();
    }
    private void textBoxForm1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DEBUGConsole.Instance.SetValueFunction("line has changed 1 : " +textBoxForm1.Text);
    }
}
```

and Form2 use it too::

```
public partial class SecondForm : Form
{
    public SecondForm(/*DEBUGConsole _ConsoleDEB*/)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DEBUGConsole.Instance.SetValueFunction("Hello 2");
    }

      private void textBoxForm2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
          DEBUGConsole.Instance.SetValueFunction("line has changed 2 : " + textBoxForm2.Text);
    }
}
```

Is that correct?
Is there only one Instance of DEBUGConsole in here?
Should it be sealed?
Is that a way to Singleton?

Thanks

Comment: This may or may not help you depending on your goals: I wrote a run-time C# expression evaluator and simple (WinForms) console window wrapper that can tell you the value of (public) members and properties and can call methods etc... at run time. It's available [on my Github page](https://github.com/BrandonLegault/ExpressionEvaluator) and as NuGet packages. Still in development

Comment: I saw that I can do both to write in console debug:

Comment: Since you'll only ever have *one* "debug console", all you have to do is add a `static` property getter in your DEBUGConsole class.  Call it, say, Instance.  Which returns the one-and-only instance of the form.  A singleton.

Comment: I can't find how to do it, I tried : internal static string SetValueFunction{      set { ListBoxDEBUG.Items.Add(value); }  }  But the ListBox is not static so it ask my an object reference....

Comment: I found how to do it, is that alright Mr Passant? (see new edit). Thanks